# RegEx для путей на файловой системе

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Помогите написать регулярку, чтобы ловила в тексте "`file://srv1/fld1/fld2/file.ext`", но при этом не ловила "`file://srv1/fld1/fld2/`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нормальный вариант**

```
@^file://(?:[^*|\\:"<>?/\s]+/)+[^*|\\:"<>?/\s]*\.[^+=\[\]:;",./?\s]+$@
```

Из имени папки исключены недопустимые символы + исключен любой пробельный символ.
Из имени файла исключены недопустимые символы. + исключен любой пробельный символ.
Имени файла может не быть вовсе.
Из расширения файла исключены недопустимые символы.

**Вариант посложнее** (это все одна регулярка)

```
@^file://(?:(?:[^.*|\\:"<>?/\s]{1,2}|[^*|\\:"<>?/\s]{3,})/)+[^*|\\:"<>?/\s]*\.[^+=\[\]:;",./?\s]+$@
```

То же, что и выше + запрещает вот такие имена директории: "." и ".."

**Пример, который пройдет первую проверку и не пройдет вторую**

```
file://root/../file.ext
```

**Пример, который пройдет обе проверки**

```
file://root/.../file.ext
```

**Самый простой вариант**

```
@^file://(?:[^/]+/)+[^/]*\.[^.]+$@
```